# Combine several chorddiag/htmlwidget plots to a single plot in R

Tags: r, plot, plotly, htmlwidgets, chord-diagram

I'm generating several `chorddiag` plots in R and would like to combine them together to a single plot. Here's an example list of 3 `chorddiag` plots:

```
library(chorddiag)
m <- matrix(c(11975,  5871, 8916, 2868,
              1951, 10048, 2060, 6171,
              8010, 16145, 8090, 8045,
              1013,   990,  940, 6907),
            byrow = TRUE,
            nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
haircolors <- c("black", "blonde", "brown", "red")
dimnames(m) <- list(haircolors,haircolors)
groupColors <- c("#000000", "#FFDD89", "#957244", "#F26223")
ll <- lapply(1:3,function(i) chorddiag(m, groupColors = groupColors, groupnamePadding = 20))
```

If these were plotly object I'd use plotly's subplot function. Is there anything equivalent for case of:

```
> class(ll[[1]])
[1] "chorddiag"  "htmlwidget"
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried the `chorddiag` package (I don't think it's on CRAN, maybe some other repos?), but the `manipulateWidget` package may be what you want.  `example(combineWidgets)` has this code:

```r
data(iris)
library(manipulateWidget); library(plotly)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'plotly'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     last_plot
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
#> The following object is masked from 'package:graphics':
#> 
#>     layout
combineWidgets(title = "The Iris dataset",
               plot_ly(iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, type = "histogram", nbinsx = 20),
               plot_ly(iris, x = ~Sepal.Width, type = "histogram", nbinsx = 20),
               plot_ly(iris, x = ~Petal.Length, type = "histogram", nbinsx = 20),
               plot_ly(iris, x = ~Petal.Width, type = "histogram", nbinsx = 20)
)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

EDITED to add:

Okay, I found `chorddiag` on Github:  https://github.com/mattflor/chorddiag/ .  After running your code, this combines the three diagrams:

```
manipulateWidgets::combineWidgets(shiny::tagList(ll))
```

They don't resize nicely; I suspect that's because `chorddiag` wants to be fullscreen, but maybe it's a problem in `manipulateWidgets`.  You'll probably have to patch one or the other.